# Explorer Robot ROS/Player interface

Tags: ros, player

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am new to ROS. I haven't done any coding of my own with it, so I reach out to you guys for some help... I have done quite a bit of player work, and I am very familiar with the way it works. I am totally lost with ROS, so if anybody has some tips for C++ programming with Qt 4, that would be very much appreciated.

Primarily, I have a robot with a player driver, but no ROS driver. It is an explorer robot. The driver for it is not part of player, so I need take the player driver and use ROS to manipulate it. I am also trying to communicate with the kinect camera and mount it to the robot. Has anybody done anything related to this?

Thanks everyone!
-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11213/explorer-robot-ros/player-interface/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There may already be a ROS Explorer driver [from Coroware](http://www.ros.org/news/2011/03/coroware-adds-ros-support-to-corobot-and-explorer.html).

If that is not satisfactory, you can port your Player driver to ROS. There are two methods:

- Invoke the Player driver (and `libplayer`) from a ROS node, as was done for the [ROS Erratic driver](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/erratic_player/html/erratic__player_8cpp_source.html).
- Convert the Player driver to a ROS node. The results are generally clean and easy to maintain. If you are interested in this approach, I can provide hints on how to proceed.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0